# PayPal GDPR pop-up occasionally breaks test with ElementClickInterceptedException

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I'm using Selenium with Python to automate a payment. This works fine most of the time but occasionally PayPal seemingly randomly breaks the automation by presenting a pop-up right before continue is normally clicked. The full error is:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button class="ppvx_btn___5-12-8 CheckoutButton_noMargin_mv-3h" id="payment-submit-btn" data-testid="submit-button-initial" data-disabled="false">...</button> is not clickable at point (242, 497). Other element would receive the click: <div class="gdprCookieBanner_buttonGroup">...</div>
```

I'm finding it difficult to fix an issue on my page because I haven't been able to replicate it while manually navigating and using the browser inspector.

The specific section on the page where the issue occurs is:

```
<div id="gdpr-container">
        <style nonce="">@font-face { font-family: "PayPalSansBig-Regular"; font-style: normal; font-display: swap; src: url('https://www.paypalobjects.com/paypal-ui/fonts/PayPalSansBig-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('https://www.paypalobjects.com/paypal-ui/fonts/PayPalSansBig-Regular.woff') format('woff'), url('https://www.paypalobjects.com/paypal-ui/fonts/PayPalSansBig-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('https://www.paypalobjects.com/paypal-ui/fonts/PayPalSansBig-Regular.svg') format('svg'); } #gdprCookieBanner { font-family: PayPalSansBig-Regular, sans-serif; } .gdprCookieBanner_container { display: none; } .ccpaCookieBanner_container { display: none; } @media only screen and (max-width: 575.98px) { .gdprHideCookieBannerMobile { display:none; } .ccpaHideCookieBannerMobile { display:none; } }</style>
        <div id="gdprCookieBanner" class="gdprCookieBanner_container" style="display: none;"><div id="gdprCookieContent_wrapper" class="gdprCookieBanner_content-container" style="display: none;"></div><div class="gdprCookieBanner_buttonGroup"><div class="gdprCookieBanner_buttonWrapper"></div></div></div>
        <script nonce="">(function () { var bannerFptiData = {}; function getFptiReqData () { return window && window.fpti && window.PAYPAL && window.PAYPAL.analytics && window.PAYPAL.analytics.instance && window.PAYPAL.analytics.instance.options && window.PAYPAL.analytics.instance.options.request && window.PAYPAL.analytics.instance.options.request.data } function getFptiPage () { return getFptiReqData() && getFptiReqData().page; } function setSessionStorage(key) { try { sessionStorage.setItem(key, true); } catch (e) { console.log('error on setting sessioStorage', e); } } function isBannerClosed () { let is_banner_closed = false; try{ if(sessionStorage.getItem("isBannerClosed") || sessionStorage.getItem("isUserAccepted") || sessionStorage.getItem("isInvisibleBanner")){ is_banner_closed = true; } } catch (e){ is_banner_closed = false; } return is_banner_closed || (false && true && !navigator.cookieEnabled); } function reasonToHideBanner(){ let reason = ''; try { if (false && true && !navigator.cookieEnabled){ reason = 'cookies are disabled'; } else if(sessionStorage.getItem("isUserAccepted")){ reason = 'User accepted or declined'; } else if(sessionStorage.getItem("isBannerClosed")){ reason = 'Banner Closed'; } else if(sessionStorage.getItem("isInvisibleBanner")){ reason = 'Invisible banner loaded'; } } catch (error) { reason=''; } return reason; } function postAjax(success, isAccept) { var xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); var endPoint = '/myaccount/privacy/cookiePrefs/accept?marketing=true&performance=true&functional=true&type=explicit_banner&country=GB&policy=gdpr_v2.1&version=v6'; if(!isAccept){ endPoint = '/myaccount/privacy/cookiePrefs/accept?marketing=false&performance=false&functional=false&type=explicit_banner&country=GB&policy=gdpr_v2.1&version=v6'; } xhr.open('GET',endPoint); xhr.withCredentials = true; xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { if (xhr.readyState > 3 && xhr.status == 200) { success(); } }; xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json','Content-Type', 'application/json'); xhr.send(null); return xhr; }; function bindGdprEvents () { var acceptAllButton = document.getElementById('acceptAllButton'); var bannerDeclineButton = document.getElementById('bannerDeclineButton'); var bannerCloseButton = document.getElementById('bannerCloseButton'); var manageCookiesLink = document.getElementById('manageCookiesLink'); var cookieStatement = document.getElementById('cookieStatement'); var cookieLanguage = document.getElementById('gdprCookieContent_wrapper'); var cookieBanner = document.getElementById('gdprCookieBanner'); var cookieBannerAcceptAll = document.getElementsByClassName("gdprCookieBanner-acceptedAll"); var trackingPageName = '' || getFptiPage() || document.title; if (manageCookiesLink) { manageCookiesLink.onclick = function() { var manageCookiesData = { e: 'cl', link: 'managecookies', pglk: trackingPageName + '|managecookies', pgln: trackingPageName + '|managecookies' }; for(var key in bannerFptiData){ manageCookiesData[key] = bannerFptiData[key]; }; window.PAYPAL.analytics.Analytics.prototype.recordClick({data: manageCookiesData}); }; } if (cookieStatement) { cookieStatement.onclick = function() { var cookieStatementData = { e: 'cl', link: 'cookieStmtLink', pglk: trackingPageName + '|cookieStmtLink', pgln: trackingPageName + '|cookieStmtLink' }; for(var key in bannerFptiData){ cookieStatementData[key] = bannerFptiData[key]; }; window.PAYPAL.analytics.Analytics.prototype.recordClick({ data: cookieStatementData }); }; } if(bannerCloseButton && cookieBanner && cookieLanguage){ bannerCloseButton.onclick = function() { hideBanner(); setSessionStorage('isBannerClosed'); var closebannerFptiData = { e: 'cl', link: 'closeBanner', pglk: trackingPageName + '|closeBanner', pgln: trackingPageName + '|closeBanner' }; for(var key in bannerFptiData){ closebannerFptiData[key] = bannerFptiData[key]; }; window.PAYPAL.analytics.Analytics.prototype.recordClick({ data: closebannerFptiData }); }; } if (acceptAllButton && cookieBanner && cookieLanguage) { acceptAllButton.onclick = function() { hideBanner(); if (false) { setSessionStorage('isUserAccepted'); } var acceptbannerFptiData = { e: 'cl', link: 'acceptcookies', pglk: trackingPageName + '|acceptcookies', pgln: trackingPageName + '|acceptcookies', c_prefs: 'T=1,P=1,F=1,type=explicit_banner' }; for(var key in bannerFptiData){ acceptbannerFptiData[key] = bannerFptiData[key]; }; window.PAYPAL.analytics.Analytics.prototype.recordClick({ data: acceptbannerFptiData }); var winFptiData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify((window && window.fpti) || {})); var updatedFptiData = { cookiebannerhidden: 'true', c_prefs: 'T=1,P=1,F=1,type=explicit_banner' }; for(var key in bannerFptiData){ updatedFptiData[key] = bannerFptiData[key]; }; for(var key in updatedFptiData){ winFptiData[key] = updatedFptiData[key]; }; window.PAYPAL.analytics.Analytics.prototype.logActivity(winFptiData); postAjax(function() { },true); }; } if (bannerDeclineButton && cookieBanner && cookieLanguage) { bannerDeclineButton.onclick = function() { hideBanner(); if (false) { setSessionStorage('isUserAccepted'); } var bannerDeclineData = { e: 'cl', link: 'declinecookies', pglk: trackingPageName + '|declinecookies', pgln: trackingPageName + '|declinecookies', c_prefs: 'T=0,P=0,F=0,type=explicit_banner' }; for(var key in bannerFptiData){ bannerDeclineData[key] = bannerFptiData[key]; }; window.PAYPAL.analytics.Analytics.prototype.recordClick({ data: bannerDeclineData }); var winFptiData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify((window && window.fpti) || {})); var updatedFptiData = { cookiebannerhidden: 'true', c_prefs: 'T=0,P=0,F=0,type=explicit_banner' }; for(var key in bannerFptiData){ updatedFptiData[key] = bannerFptiData[key]; }; for(var key in updatedFptiData){ winFptiData[key] = updatedFptiData[key]; }; window.PAYPAL.analytics.Analytics.prototype.logActivity(winFptiData); postAjax(function() { },false); }; } window.hideGdprBanner = function () { var cookieBannerUi = document.getElementById('gdprCookieBanner'); if (cookieBannerUi && cookieBannerUi.className.indexOf('gdprHideCookieBannerMobile') === -1) { cookieBannerUi.className += " gdprHideCookieBannerMobile"; } }; window.showGdprBanner = function () { var cookieBannerUi = document.getElementById('gdprCookieBanner'); if (cookieBannerUi) { cookieBannerUi.className = cookieBannerUi.className.replace("gdprHideCookieBannerMobile",""); } }; document.body.addEventListener("focus", function (event) { if (event.target.type === 'text' || event.target.type === 'number' || event.target.type === 'password' || event.target.type === 'email' || event.target.type === 'select-one') { window.hideGdprBanner(); } }, true); } function adjustPaddingTop(){ var cookieBannerAcceptAll = document.getElementsByClassName("gdprCookieBanner-acceptedAll"); if(cookieBannerAcceptAll.length > 0){ var cookieBanner = document.getElementById('gdprCookieBanner'); var bannerHeight = cookieBanner ? cookieBanner.clientHeight : 0; if(cookieBannerAcceptAll && cookieBannerAcceptAll[0] && bannerHeight){ cookieBannerAcceptAll[0].style.paddingTop = bannerHeight/16 +'em'; } } }; var isPaddingBottomAdded = false, bannerPaddingBottom = ""; function adjustPaddingBottom(addListener){ if (undefined || !false) { return; } function adjustPaddingBottomEvent() { var cookieBannerAcceptAll = document.getElementsByClassName("gdprCookieBanner-acceptedAll"); if(cookieBannerAcceptAll.length > 0){ var bodyPaddingBottom = cookieBannerAcceptAll[0].style.paddingBottom; var cookieBanner = document.getElementById('gdprCookieBanner'); if(cookieBannerAcceptAll && cookieBannerAcceptAll[0] && cookieBanner.style.display != 'none') { if (bodyPaddingBottom === "" || (isPaddingBottomAdded && bannerPaddingBottom === bodyPaddingBottom)) { var cookieBannerContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('gdprCookieBanner_container'); var bannerBottomHeight = cookieBannerContainer.length > 0 ? parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(cookieBannerContainer[0]).bottom.replace("px", "")) : 0; var bannerHeight = cookieBanner ? cookieBanner.clientHeight : 0; bannerPaddingBottom = ((bannerHeight + bannerBottomHeight) / 16) + 'em'; cookieBannerAcceptAll[0].style.paddingBottom = bannerPaddingBottom; isPaddingBottomAdded = true; } else if (isPaddingBottomAdded && bannerPaddingBottom !== bodyPaddingBottom) { isPaddingBottomAdded = false; } } } } if (addListener) { adjustPaddingBottomEvent(); window.addEventListener('resize', adjustPaddingBottomEvent);  } else { var cookieBannerAcceptAll = document.getElementsByClassName("gdprCookieBanner-acceptedAll"); if(cookieBannerAcceptAll && cookieBannerAcceptAll[0]){ window.removeEventListener('resize', adjustPaddingBottomEvent); adjustPaddingBottomEvent(); if (isPaddingBottomAdded && cookieBannerAcceptAll[0].style.paddingBottom === bannerPaddingBottom) { cookieBannerAcceptAll[0].style.removeProperty('padding-bottom'); } } } }; window.bindGdprEvents = bindGdprEvents; function cookieDisabled() { if (navigator.cookieEnabled === false) return "true"; else if (navigator.cookieEnabled === true) return "false"; else return "undefined"; }; function gdprSetup () { var cookieLanguage = document.getElementById('gdprCookieContent_wrapper'); var cookieBanner = document.getElementById('gdprCookieBanner'); var manageLink = document.getElementById('manageCookiesLink'); var acceptAllLink = document.getElementById('acceptAllButton'); var trackingPageName = '' || getFptiPage() || document.title; if(!isBannerClosed()){ document.body.className = document.body.className += " gdprCookieBanner-acceptedAll"; if(undefined){ adjustPaddingTop(); window.addEventListener('resize', adjustPaddingTop);   document.body.className = document.body.className += " top-cookie-banner-enabled";    } enableEvents(true); } var pageName = trackingPageName || getFptiPage() || document.title; var winFptiData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify((window && window.fpti) || {})); bannerFptiData = { page:  'main:privacy:policy:gdpr_v2.1', pgrp:  'main:privacy:policy', displaypage: window.fpti.pgrp, ppage: 'privacy_banner', bannertype: 'cookiebanner', ccpg: 'GB', flag: 'gdpr_v2.1', bannerversion: 'v6', bannersource: 'ConsentNodeServ', bannervariant: 'hidden', xe: '', xt: '', eligibility_reason: 'true', is_native: 'false', cookie_disabled: cookieDisabled(), reason_to_hide: reasonToHideBanner() }; if(false){ bannerFptiData.isNativeBannerHidden = true; } for(var key in bannerFptiData){ winFptiData[key] = bannerFptiData[key]; }; window.PAYPAL.analytics.Analytics.prototype.logActivity(winFptiData); if (manageLink) { manageLink.setAttribute('pagename', (pageName + '|managecookies')); } if (acceptAllLink) { acceptAllLink.setAttribute('pagename', (pageName + '|acceptcookies')); } bindGdprEvents(); }; function hideBanner() { var cookieLanguage = document.getElementById('gdprCookieContent_wrapper'); var cookieBanner = document.getElementById('gdprCookieBanner'); if(cookieLanguage && cookieBanner){ cookieLanguage.style.display = 'none'; cookieBanner.style.display = 'none'; }else { return false; } window.removeEventListener('resize', adjustPaddingTop); var cookieBannerAcceptAll = document.getElementsByClassName("gdprCookieBanner-acceptedAll"); if(cookieBannerAcceptAll && cookieBannerAcceptAll[0]){ cookieBannerAcceptAll[0].style.removeProperty('padding-top'); } enableEvents(false); document.body.className = document.body.className.replace("gdprCookieBanner-acceptedAll",""); document.body.className = document.body.className.replace("top-cookie-banner-enabled",""); return true; } function isPageReady () { var cookieBannerUi = document.getElementById('gdprCookieBanner'); return !!(cookieBannerUi && getFptiReqData()); } function enableFocusEvent(addListener){ if(!false || undefined){ return; } var cookieBanner = document.getElementById('gdprCookieBanner'); function focusIn(e) { if(cookieBanner && cookieBanner.style.display != 'none'){ var activeElement = document.activeElement; if(((activeElement.getBoundingClientRect().bottom) > (cookieBanner.getBoundingClientRect().top)) && !activeElement.parentElement.nodeName.includes("UL")){ activeElement.scrollIntoView({block: 'center'}); } }else{ document.removeEventListener("focusin", focusIn); } } if(addListener){ document.addEventListener("focusin",focusIn); } } function enableEvents(enable){ adjustPaddingBottom(enable); enableFocusEvent(enable); } var maxRetries = 34, bannerhidden=false; function triggerBanner() { if (isPageReady()) { if (isBannerClosed()) { hideBanner(); } if(true){ setSessionStorage('isInvisibleBanner'); } gdprSetup(); } else { if (isBannerClosed() && !bannerhidden ) { bannerhidden=hideBanner(); } if (maxRetries-- > 0) { setTimeout(triggerBanner, 150); } else { if (isBannerClosed()) { hideBanner(); } if(!isBannerClosed() && document.getElementById('gdprCookieBanner') && !document.body.className.includes("gdprCookieBanner-acceptedAll")){ document.body.className = document.body.className += " gdprCookieBanner-acceptedAll"; if(undefined){ adjustPaddingTop(); window.addEventListener('resize', adjustPaddingTop);   document.body.className = document.body.className += " top-cookie-banner-enabled"; } enableEvents(true); } var acceptAllButton = document.getElementById('acceptAllButton'); var bannerDeclineButton = document.getElementById('bannerDeclineButton'); var bannerCloseButton = document.getElementById('bannerCloseButton'); var cookieBanner = document.getElementById('gdprCookieBanner'); if ( acceptAllButton ) { acceptAllButton.onclick = function() { hideBanner(); if (false) { setSessionStorage('isUserAccepted'); } postAjax(function() { },true); }; } if ( bannerDeclineButton ) { bannerDeclineButton.onclick = function() { hideBanner(); if (false) { setSessionStorage('isUserAccepted'); } postAjax(function() { },false); }; } if ( bannerCloseButton ) { bannerCloseButton.onclick = function() { hideBanner(); setSessionStorage('isBannerClosed'); } } if(true){ setSessionStorage('isInvisibleBanner'); } } } } triggerBanner(); })();</script>
      <style nonce="">#gdprCookieBanner{z-index:9999}#ccpaCookieBanner{z-index:9999}</style></div>
```

I am using `WebDriverWait` for most of my testing, but occasionally, I encounter a pop-up that appears sporadically. I believe I need to use an `if/else` statement with a regular `driver.find_element()` to handle this situation. What element should I use for the `if` statement, as I do not want to attempt to click the button if the pop-up is not present?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code just before the pop-up is occurred.

```
intermittent_element = driver.find_elements(By.ID, "gdprCookieBanner")
if len(intermittent_element) > 0:
    intermittent_element[0].click()
```

**NOTE:** Ensure you use `find_elements` and not `find_element`.

**Explanation:** `find_elements` won't stop the execution by throwing any exception. So if the element/pop-up is found, then it will `click()` on it, else it will continue execution.

Comment: Thanks but this does not seem to work. I don't think `gdprCookieBanner` is the correct element to find (but I don't know what is) as it returns true each time. However I have not yet seen the pop-up. Because it returns true, it tries to click a button that's not there and I get a `ElementNotInteractableException`.

Comment: I gave `gdprCookieBanner ` out of the assumption that the HTML you shared in the question was of pop-up. You need to first reproduce the pop-up and get the HTML of it. Then locate the element in the pop-up and use that locator in the `if` condition. Should work. Good luck.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. The find_elements no exception things is super useful! Unfortunately though, that is the problem. I've been manually going through the process all day but it still hasn't popped up for me yet. The error said the element that would get the click is `gdprCookieBanner_buttonGroup` - that's why I included what I thought was the relevant section.